Understanding Recursive Method Call Order and Output in C#
I have a C# program with recursive method calls, and I'm trying to understand the order of execution and output produced by the program. Here's the code snippet:
using System;

public class HelloWorld
{
    static int a = new int();
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ab(a = 1);
        Console.WriteLine("Main---" + a);
    }
    public static void ab(int a)
    {
        if (a != 10)
        {
            a++;
            Console.WriteLine("ab-----" + a);
            ab(a);
            b(a);
        }
    }
    public static void b(int a)
    {
        if (a < 10)
        {
            a++;
            Console.WriteLine("b-----------" + a);
        }
    }
}

The output of this program is as follows:
ab-----2
ab-----3
ab-----4
ab-----5
ab-----6
ab-----7
ab-----8
ab-----9
ab-----10
b-----------10
b-----------9
b-----------8
b-----------7
b-----------6
b-----------5
b-----------4
b-----------3
Main---1

I notice that the b method prints its values in reverse order compared to the ab method. I expect the b method to print its values in ascending order similar to the ab method. Could someone explain why this happens and how the order of execution works in recursive calls in this scenario? Additionally, I want to confirm if my interpretation of the behavior is correct.
Thank you for your help!

b is unwrapping the calls to ab because the ab recursion happens before any call to b.

Instead of just reading the output like you were a regular user, actually be a developer. Use the debugger to step through the code line by line and then you'll see exactly what it does and why. If you don't know how to debug code, stop what you're doing and learn that first. It's a required skill for all developers.

I acknowledge the importance of debugging, and I've already undertaken that process. However, despite debugging, I'm still struggling to grasp the flow of execution. That's why I'm seeking assistance here—to deepen my understanding of the code's behavior beyond what debugging alone can provide.

What exactly you struggling on? "Line-by-line" debug suggestion supposed to explain the flow, as well as console output. You call ab first time from Main and it starts with 2, then recursively repeat ab call until condition a != 10. As b call declared AFTER recursive ab call - b won't be executed until whole chain of ab will be completed (again, until a != 10). And when it is - then b comes in. So first b call would be after last ab call, and last b call runs at first ab call, when int a is 2.

Just to clarify, the key thing here is that its recursively calls ab(int a) and ONLY starts to call b(int a) once a has reached 10. So the first call to b(int a) will have a as 10.

Your main first calls ab() (with all its recursive calls), then prints the main tag then ends the prigramm. So the main tag must be printed last.
Your very first (and outmost) call to ab() prints the first ab tag with the initial number, then makes some recoursive calls to ab() and then calls b() which prints the b tag for the very first value and then ends. Thus every other output (from any of the recoursive calls to ab() must be after your first ab tag and before your first b tag.
In that fashion, each recursive call to ab() will have their call to b() as their last action. That means the call to b() with the lowes value will be the last, as all innermore calls (with higher values) must have occured before.
The following figure tries to demonstrate the nesting and execution order of the recursive calls:
ab(1)
    ab(2)
        ab(3)
            ...
        b(3)
    b(2)
b(1)


It's worth changing your code to avoid mutation (i.e. a++) and to eliminate odd naming ab versus b and the three difference instantiations of a.
Let's name the two methods X and Y and the integer in each i and j respectively.
I also added code to indent based on depth.
Now the code looks like this:
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main...");
        X(1);
        Console.WriteLine("...Main");
    }
    
    public static void X(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{new String(' ', i)}X({i})...");
        if (i != 10)
        {
            X(i + 1);
            Y(i + 1);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"{new String(' ', i)}...X({i})");
    }
    
    public static void Y(int j)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{new String(' ', j)}Y({j})...");
        Console.WriteLine($"{new String(' ', j)}...Y({j})");
    }
}

The output is:
Main...
 X(1)...
  X(2)...
   X(3)...
    X(4)...
     X(5)...
      X(6)...
       X(7)...
        X(8)...
         X(9)...
          X(10)...
          ...X(10)
          Y(10)...
          ...Y(10)
         ...X(9)
         Y(9)...
         ...Y(9)
        ...X(8)
        Y(8)...
        ...Y(8)
       ...X(7)
       Y(7)...
       ...Y(7)
      ...X(6)
      Y(6)...
      ...Y(6)
     ...X(5)
     Y(5)...
     ...Y(5)
    ...X(4)
    Y(4)...
    ...Y(4)
   ...X(3)
   Y(3)...
   ...Y(3)
  ...X(2)
  Y(2)...
  ...Y(2)
 ...X(1)
...Main

Now you can see all of the starts to method X happen before an Y is called  - and in fact, method X(10) completes before the call to Y(10).
Hopefully this is a little easier to see the reasoning of the flow.
